Playwright Error: Process from config.webServer was not able to start. Exit code: 2
Followed the instructions on https://playwright.dev/docs/intro#installing-playwright, and got this error:
Error: Process from config.webServer was not able to start. Exit code: 2
My setup is React with Typescript and Vite.
The command I use:
playwright test
The config file web server part:
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './e2e',
  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  reporter: 'html',
  use: {
      trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },

  projects: [
    {
        name: 'chromium',
        use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
    },

    {
        name: 'firefox',
        use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
    },

    {
        name: 'webkit',
        use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
    },
  ],
  webServer: {
      command: 'npm run build && npm run dev',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
      reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
   },
});

The HTML Report says the same thing.
What am I doing wrong?

Does npm run build && npm run dev work without Playwright? Can you share a [mcve] with your package.json and a minimal version of the app you're running? I don't see anything obviously wrong here--you're using totally standard config and commands. Thanks.

Thank you @ggorlen I had a problem with the build:
The run build failed, fixed the TS error and Playwright works well.
